# Laravel 4: setting correct scheme and domain for pagination and form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is probably an oversight on my part, but I am wondering what's the correct way to set the default pagenate base url.

Our domain is on `https://domain.com` and we have set config `app.url` as such, but pagination still appear to use `http://domain.com` (note the scheme is `http` instead of `https`) when generating url in view. I am wondering how to do this without writing `setBaseUrl` everywhere.

(We are using Laravel 4.1)

**Update**: we got the same problem with `Form::open` as well, where is the setting that make Laravel realize we want url with `https` instead of `http`? Shouldn't it be using `app.url` as a base url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out the answer myself:

Since our server is behind a reverse proxy (nginx), while content is served as HTTPS, the proxying is done with HTTP, so we should set following to nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme; //or just `https`
```

(same as your `proxy_pass upstream` block)

Then we can use [Trusting Proxies](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html) feature as such:

```
$proxies = Config::get('app.trusted_proxies');

// trust any balancer
if ($proxies === '*')
{
    $proxies = array( Request::getClientIp() );
}

// else trust an array of IPs
if ($proxies && is_array($proxies))
{
    Request::setTrustedProxies($proxies);
}
```

(This can be added to `bootstrap/start.php`. Laravel use Symfony Request library, which is why we linked to their document, as this feature is not documented in Laravel docs)